# Reverse order of foreach list items

Tags: php

I would like to reverse the order of this code's list items. Basically it's a set of years going from oldest to recent and I am trying to reverse that output.

```
<?php
    $j=1;     
    foreach ( $skills_nav as $skill ) {
        $a = '<li><a href="#" data-filter=".'.$skill->slug.'">';
        $a .= $skill->name;                 
        $a .= '</a></li>';
        echo $a;
        echo "\n";
        $j++;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 212, accepted):

#### Walking Backwards

If you're looking for a purely PHP solution, you can also simply count backwards through the list, access it front-to-back:

```php
$accounts = Array(
  '@jonathansampson',
  '@f12devtools',
  '@ieanswers'
);

$index = count($accounts);

while($index) {
  echo sprintf("<li>%s</li>", $accounts[--$index]);
}
```

The above sets `$index` to the total number of elements, and then begins accessing them back-to-front, reducing the index value for the next iteration.

#### Reversing the Array

You could also leverage the [`array_reverse` function](https://www.php.net/array_reverse) to invert the values of your array, allowing you to access them in reverse order:

```php
$accounts = Array(
  '@jonathansampson',
  '@f12devtools',
  '@ieanswers'
);

foreach ( array_reverse($accounts) as $account ) {
  echo sprintf("<li>%s</li>", $account);
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php will be better if you want simply reverse array, and you know that it is sorted

Comment: @Slawek If the array is already ordered, why would reversing necessarily be *better* than counting through it backwards?

Comment: @JonathanSampson - because if you reverse array before using it in loop, you can simply change it in future. When you bind loop logic with data, changing order will force to change also the loop.

Comment: @Slawek I'm not sure I follow. Counting backwards through an array is a common practice, and doesn't require any caution when handling the array in the future since it doesn't actually modify the array.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Ok, IMO array filtering/sorting should be done in different layer than view. View should receive data for simple displaying. Counting backwards in view is unnecessary logic for me. If you want to change array order you need to change view logic.

Comment: @Slawek I'm not in disagreement there. Thought I don't see any indication the user is following any sort of MVC pattern. Certainly, if they have a controller, or a model, it may be wiser to sort the array there in many cases.

Comment: use of array_reverse($accounts) in foreach is a performance issue.

Assign it to an another variable first and then use this variable in foreach.

Comment: Any easy way to do that with a Objects?

Comment: Not very good for performance, but definitely more readable code :-)

Answer (score 35):

Or you could use the [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) function.

Answer (score 28):

`array_reverse()` does not alter the source array, but returns a new array. (See [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php).)  So you either need to store the new array first or just use function within the declaration of your for loop.

```
<?php 
    $input = array('a', 'b', 'c');
    foreach (array_reverse($input) as $value) {
        echo $value."\n";
    }
?>
```

The output will be:

```
c
b
a
```

So, to address to OP, the code becomes:

```
<?php
    $j=1;     
    foreach ( array_reverse($skills_nav) as $skill ) {
        $a = '<li><a href="#" data-filter=".'.$skill->slug.'">';
        $a .= $skill->name;                 
        $a .= '</a></li>';
        echo $a;
        echo "\n";
        $j++;
}
```

Lastly, I'm going to guess that the `$j` was either a counter used in an initial attempt to get a reverse walk of `$skills_nav`, or a way to count the `$skills_nav` array.  If the former, it should be removed now that you have the correct solution. If the latter, it can be replaced, outside of the loop, with a `$j = count($skills_nav)`.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't mind destroying the array (or a temp copy of it) you can do:

```
$stack = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");

while ($fruit = array_pop($stack)){
    echo $fruit . "\n<br>"; 
}
```

produces:

```
raspberry 
apple 
banana 
orange
```

I think this solution reads cleaner than fiddling with an index and you are less likely to introduce index handling mistakes, but the problem with it is that your code will likely take slightly longer to run if you have to create a temporary copy of the array first.
Fiddling with an index is likely to run faster, and it may also come in handy if you actually need to reference the index, as in:

```
$stack = array("orange", "banana", "apple", "raspberry");
$index = count($stack) - 1;
while($index > -1){
    echo $stack[$index] ." is in position ". $index . "\n<br>";
    $index--;
}
```

But as you can see, you have to be very careful with the index...

Comment: The `array_pop` approach is 3 times slower than the `array_reverse` approach: https://3v4l.org/3jaTT

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you just need to reverse an indexed array (not associative or multidimensional) a simple [for loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) would suffice:

```
$fruits = ['bananas', 'apples', 'pears'];
for($i = count($fruits)-1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
    echo $fruits[$i] . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function to create own sorting rules

Comment: This will not be performant since the array is already in order (just reverse the order).

Answer (score 2):

If your array is populated through an SQL Query consider reversing the result in MySQL, ie :

```
SELECT * FROM model_input order by creation_date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have Boolean false values in your array, you could use next code based on internal pointer functions:

```
$array = ['banana', 'apple', 'pineapple', 'lemon'];

$value = end($array);
while ($value !== false) {
     // In case you need a key
    $key = key($array);

    // Do something you need to
    echo $key . ' => ' . $value . "\n";

    // Move pointer
    $value = prev($array);
}
```

This solution works for associative arrays with arbitrary keys and do not require altering existing or creating a new one.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
    $j=1; 


      array_reverse($skills_nav);   


    foreach ( $skills_nav as $skill ) {
        $a = '<li><a href="#" data-filter=".'.$skill->slug.'">';
        $a .= $skill->name;                 
        $a .= '</a></li>';
        echo $a;
        echo "\n";
        $j++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: array_reverse() does not alter the source array, but returns a new array.