# Reverse order of years

Tags: php

I am trying to implement the array_reverse function into this foreach array, I believe I'm calling the wrong variables in line 3(well, 4)

```
<?php
    $j=1;
    $skill_slugs = array_reverse( $skill_slugs );

    foreach ($skills as $skill) {               
        $skill = get_term_by( 'slug', trim(htmlentities($skill)), 'skill');
        if($skill) {
            $skill_slug = $skill->slug;             
            $skill_slugs .= $skill_slug . ",";
            $a = '<li><a href="#" data-filter=".'.$skill_slug.'">';
            $a .= $skill->name;                 
            $a .= '</a></li>';
            echo $a;
            echo "\n";
            $j++;
        }         
    }
?>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You are reseting $skill on every iteration?

Comment: @user1420650 Is this not the same question you [just asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777597/reverse-order-of-foreach-list-items/10777617#10777617)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're wanting to cycle over the newly-reversed array...

```
foreach ($skills as $skill)
```

Should be

```
foreach ($skill_slugs as $skill)
```

#### Update

```
// This array is populated within the if-block below
$slugs = array();

// Foreach item in the reversed array, assign a handle of "skill_slug"
foreach ( array_reverse( $skill_slugs ) as $skill_slug ) {

  // Attempt to get Term Data from WordPress
  $s = get_term_by( 'slug', trim(htmlentities($skill_slug)), 'skill' );

  // If Term Data was returned, increment $j and proceed
  if ( $s && $j++ ) {

    // Push Term slug into our $slugs array
    array_push( $slugs, $s->slug );

    // Output a new list-item for this Term
    printf("<li><a href='#' data-filter='%s'>%s</a></li>", $s->slug, $s->name);

  }

}
```

There's a lot of confusing ambiguity here with the names you've chosen for each variable. I'm trying to break down on that just a bit here. Additionally, You don't need so many `echo` statements, so I've reduced it to a single formatted string. Lastly, I'm pushing your slugs onto an array, rather than concatenating them onto a string. If you want to list them with commas inbetween, juse `join()`:

```
$slugs = array( "PHP", "JavaScript", "C#" );

// PHP, JavaScript, C#
echo join( ", ", $slugs );
```

Comment: @jons Probably closer but no reverse yet, I updated $skills to $skill_slugs: http://pastie.org/3979495

Comment: You're very helpful thanks for the breakdown. I believe I didn't copy enough code over as there are other sections calling the same variables. See full code here: http://pastie.org/4021542 Line 18 is where I did the replacement but I'm feeling like the section below needs edits too.