# Getting reverse array to work

Tags: php

In reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777597/reverse-order-of-foreach-list-items) question, I'm struggling to reverse an array. I've tried the following but don't think this is correct, where am I going wrong?

```
<?php $rows = get_field('news');
    $counter = 1;
    $rows_full = array_reverse($rows);
    foreach($rows as $row) { ?>
        <p style="margin-bottom:20px;font-size:14px;"><?php echo $row['news_description']; ?></p>
<?php $counter++ } ?>
```

Comment: You are probably better of by changing the query to let the database sort for you (i.e change ASC to DESC or vice-versa).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change like this

```
 $rows_full = array_reverse($rows);
foreach($rows_full as $row) { ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
 foreach($rows as $row) { ?>
```

Should be:

```
foreach($rows_full as $row) { ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're reversing the array and then never using it. Try this instead:

```
foreach($rows_full as $row) { ...
```

Answer (score 1):

[`array_reverse`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) does not reverse the array in-place, but instead returns a new array that is reversed.

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4);
$rev_arr = array_reverse($arr);

print_r($arr);         // prints [1,2,3,4,5]
print_r($rev_arr);     // prints [5,4,3,2,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

In foreach you are using `$rows` change it to `$rows_full`

```
$rows_full = array_reverse($rows);
    foreach($rows_full as $row) { ?>
```