# iterate reverse over php associative array

Tags: php, arrays

How does one iterate in reverse over php associative array?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10777617/1032531 gives solutions for a non-associated array.

My attempt:

```
$a=['5'=>'five','3'=>'three','7'=>'seven'];
var_dump($a);
foreach($a as $k=>$v){echo("$k $v\n");}
$a=array_reverse($a);
var_dump($a);
foreach($a as $k=>$v){echo("$k $v\n");}
```

produces the following results:

```
array(3) {
  [5]=>
  string(4) "five"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "three"
  [7]=>
  string(5) "seven"
}
5 five
3 three
7 seven
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "seven"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "three"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "five"
}
0 seven
1 three
2 five
```

I wish to preserve the keys, and return:

```
array(3) {
  [5]=>
  string(4) "five"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "three"
  [7]=>
  string(5) "seven"
}
5 five
3 three
7 seven
array(3) {
  [7]=>
  string(5) "seven"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "three"
  [5]=>
  string(4) "five"
}
7 seven
3 three
5 five
```

Comment: Why not use array_reverse and iterate over?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `$a=array_reverse($a,true);` instead of `$a=array_reverse($a);` for keep key.

`array_reverse()` have a second optional parameter for preserve keys. default value is false.

Read [doc here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php)

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You were very close - you had all the key words already - and just need to remember that the PHP manual is your friend :)

The [manual page for `array_reverse`](http://php.net/array_reverse) lists an optional argument `$preserve_keys`, which defaults to false.

So you just need to change `$a=array_reverse($a);` to `$a=array_reverse($a, true);`, and you should get the result you were after.