# While showing the lasts results first

Tags: php

I've made a while to get images in a folder and show with description on DB.
How can I change to show the lasts images first?
I tried using 2 whiles but I hadnt success
This is my code:

```
<?PHP
                    $directory = "images/uploads/promocoes/";
                    $images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");
                    $i=0;
                    foreach($images as $image){
                        echo '
                            <div class="six columns category nature">
                        ';
                        if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
                            echo '
                                <form action="frmdeleteimage.php?img='.$image.'&checkbox=promocoes" method="post">
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="checkbox" value="promocoes" checked>
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Excluir imagem">
                                </form>
                            ';
                        }
                        $filename = basename($image);
                        //$filename = filter_var($filename, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                        //$filename = $filename-1;
                        $selectp = "SELECT name from page_promocoes WHERE img='$filename';";
                        $resultp = mysql_query($selectp);
                        while ($rowp = mysql_fetch_row($resultp)) {
                            $rowsp[] = $rowp;
                        }
                        echo '
                            <div class="portofoliothumb">
                        ';
                        echo '<h5>';
                        echo $rowsp[$i][0];
                        $i=$i+1;
                        echo '</h5>';
                        echo '
                                <a href="'.$image.'" style="background-image:url('.$image.')"></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        ';
                    }
                ?>
```

Comment: Do you have result array then reverse loop it using a `for loop`by finding the count then use decrements iteration then you can get your result

Comment: What is your actual need? Need to show the images in the descending order of the records in database?

Comment: @sujivasagam I get images from folder, description I get from db using image file name

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777597/reverse-order-of-foreach-list-items

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reverse order of foreach list items](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777597/reverse-order-of-foreach-list-items)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use asort to sort the files of the folder

```
$files = array();   

$directory = "images/uploads/promocoes/";
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");


foreach (scandir($directory) as $file) {
    if (in_array($file, $ignored)) continue;
    $files[$file] = filemtime($dir . '/' . $file);
}

arsort($files);
```

After you sort the files in the desceding order, you can use your query

Answer (score 0):

$selectp = "SELECT name from page_promocoes WHERE img='$filename' ORDER BY img DESC LIMIT 1;";

Comment: This select just get description

Comment: Try to make $last_id added.. 
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert_lastid.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use`array_reverse()` on the resulting array from `glob()`.

After this line:

```
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");
```

Add this:

```
$images = array_reverse($images);
```